# password_verify matchea pero no cumple funcion (no returna true)

Tags: php

tengo un login en php... paso un password por "hash_password" y luego quiero verificarlo con "password_verify" me fije por medio de echos que todo matchee el problema es que dentro del password_verify tengo una funcion que deberia emprimir un echo y no lo hace... supongo sera no esta cumpliendose algun requisito adjunto codigo...

```
class test extends Connect {
    public function probar($pass = '$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz
    ', $usu = 'amor'){
        $this->connect();
$passwordENCODE = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
$resultado = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `name` = :name;");
$resultado->bindParam(':name', $usu, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultado->execute();
$count = $resultado->rowCount();
$row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
session_start();

if ($count == 1 && !empty($row)) {
    print_r($row);
    $_SESSION['account'] = array('name' => $usu, 'pass' => $passwordENCODE);
    echo '<br>';
    print_R($_SESSION['account']);
    $auth_pass = $row['pass'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $auth_pass;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $pass;
    if(password_verify($pass, $auth_pass)){
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    }
} else if ($count == 0) {
    
  echo 'nada';  
}
    }
}

$test = new test();
$test->probar();
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => amor [pass] => $argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) print_r $row1
Array ( [name] => amor [pass] => $argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$dmk4cE11T2RRWXhrWGtTdA$D5BxidYkCG7EFznXGtvivZCnv7L14VsVqyFhfjmJXdI ) print_r session1
auth pass$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz
pass param$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz
```

Comment: El hash se crea cuando insertas el registro, guardando dicho hash en la base de datos, luego, para verificarlo obtienes el hash guardado y compruebas con `password_verify`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/256746/29967) para más detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que te estas haciendo un lio al poner el **hash** de la contraseña como parámetro por omisión en la función **probar()**.

Yo haria estos cambios para que funcionara bien:

1. Donde pone esto:

```
public function probar($pass = '$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz
    ', $usu = 'amor'){
```

pondría esto:

```
public function probar($pass, $usu = 'amor'){
```

- y donde pones esto:

```
$test->probar();
```

pondría la password a comprobar (**y no el hash!**), por ejemplo:

```
$test->probar("microntraseña");
```

pues representa que el hash ya lo tienes en el `$row['pass']` que recuperas de la base de datos.  Y si no es así asegúrate de almacenarlo primero en la tabla correctamente antes de usarlo en este método de esta clase.

Comment: ya lo probe y sigu retornando false... probe dadmdole a password_verify los parametros del ejemplo de la documentacion y me retorna true pero no imprime el echo "contraseña valida"...

Comment: Los outputs que muestro en mi pregunta muestran el row['pass'] y la pass que le doy ambos son iguales pero retorna false.

Comment: O sea, perdona eh, ¿me estas diciendo que el usuario, para hacer el login, tiene que escribir `$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz` en el campo de contraseña del formulario que tenga de login tu web?   Yo, perdona, pero si llegamos a estos niveles en Internet, cojo y me bajo :-)

Comment: Bromas aparte... el password verify no compara cadenas iguales, sino que interpreta el segundo parámetro (el hash), se da cuenta de su codificación (fíjate que empieza por **$argon2i**), y se la aplica al primer parámetro para que internamente sus algoritmos le digan si son equivalentes o no.  Es por eso que ambos parámetros del password_veriry **no** pueden ser iguales.

Comment: ¿No recuerdas la cadena de texto que generó el hash `$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$LmxXeXQzMHpac2pvRWJz` que está almacenado en la base de datos?  Pues esa es la cadena que debes pasarle en el `$test->probar("cadena_de_texto_que_genero_el_hash_guardado_en_la_base_de_datos")` para que funcione

Comment: Por ejemplo, si la cadena de texto fuera **password123** y en la base de datos estuviera almacenado este hash: `$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$Sk9kYkFvenhxYjNUSEZvag$QXiK5aO7MOFw0zJJTU0L6MurgzmNba997qdU/ipK24M` (que acabo de calcular para ella), e hicieras un `$test->probar("password123");` entonces te saldria bien.  Pruébalo cambiando el contenido de la columna "pass" de tu base de datos para ese usuario y lo verás.

Comment: Usando ese sistema de hash, la contraseña nunca se guarda en formato plano en la base de datos, sino codificado, y eso incrementa mucho la seguridad, claro, y por eso usamos password_verify despues, pues el hash que generas con `password_hash()` no siempre es el mismo, no siempre da el mismo resultado, sino que varia cada vez, pero password_verify() sabe como compararlo con una cadena de texto normal y decidir si representan lo mismo o no.  Lo que tu te crees que hace es mas bien un `if($pass == $auth_pass)` y no es así, como acabo de explicar. ¿Se me entiende? :-S

Comment: ya probe con los parametros de la pregunta (retorna false), poniendo parametros del ejemplo de la documentacion (retorna true) y los parametros que me pasaste vos (retorna true) pero sigo con lo mismo. No imprime en pantalla el echo que le paso.

Comment: aqui esta el paste.. https://pastebin.com/T8psxFPk saque los echo de pass y todo para solo dejar el var dump que retona true y ver si me lo estaba perdiendo por ahi el echo del password verify pero no sale.

Comment: Quita el var_dump... tal como está ahora dudo que salga bien pues un var_dump no devuelve "true" o "false", sino que debe estar escribiendote `bool(true)` en la salida, pero no deja procesar lo siguiente (lo he probado)... dejalo como estaba en la pregunta, así:  `if(password_verify($pass, $auth_pass)){` y deberia salir bien

Comment: Ahi salio el echo. No conocia esa interaccion del var_dump. Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarm!

Comment: Sí, tanto **var_dump()** como **print_r()** escupen a la salida su resultado en el momento de su ejecución si se ejecutan tal cual (aunque hay forma de pararlos).  Lo que no hacen es devolver valores booleanos, sino que devuelven un volcado del valor de la variable que contienen en su parámetro en modo texto simplemente.